# How do I show that if $m^2 + n^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ then at least one of them is divisible by $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I show that if $$m^2 + n^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$ then at least one of $\{m,n,p\}$ is divisible by 5?

Comment: At least one of *what* is divisible by $5$?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite standard. The only squares mod 5 are 0, 1 and 4. Then if you have that the sum of tree squares that gives 0, at least one of them has to be zero (just check all posibilities $1+1+1=3\neq 0,1+1+4=1\neq 0$ and so on).

Finally the only number with square 0, is zero

Answer (score 0):

If $k \equiv 0,\pm 1, \pm 2 \pmod 5$ then $k^2 \equiv 0,1,-1\pmod 5$.

So none of $m,n$ or $p$ are divisible by $5$ then none of $m,n,p \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and none of $m^2, n^2, p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod  5$.  So all of $m^2, n^2, p^2 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$.

So $m^2 + n^2 + p^2 \equiv \pm 1 + \pm 1 + \pm 1$. The only possible values for those is $-3,-1,1$ or $3$.  So $m^2 + n^2 +p^2$ being divisible by $5$ is impossible unless one of $m,n$ or $p$ is divisible by $5$.